# Arguments not being applied to Google chromedriver in Selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium with python and chromedriver (webdriver) on OS X (Yosemite)

I'm trying to add arguments to my driver instance like so:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

The browser window creates fine but it doesn't maximise.

Even ignoring that particular argument, no matter which arguments I supply they never seem to be applied. Am I missing something?

**Edit:** Seems I can pass the mobile emulation options without any problems. So the issue might be contained to passing argument type options.

Comment: What about calling `driver.maximize_window()` after?

Comment: That works as a quick fix, thanks. However, I'll still need to be able to apply other Chromium args in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it correctly, [`--start-maximized` just doesn't work on mac](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=774).

To maximize the chrome window - use [`maximize_window()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.maximize_window):

> `maximize_window()`
>
> Maximizes the current window that webdriver is using

```
driver.maximize_window()
```

Comment: The page loads with a red cross on a lock icon regardless of whether I pass the argument or not. The presence of the argument doesn't appear to make any difference for the URL you presented.

Comment: @Devin oops, yeah, it was a bad example. Anyway, the point is - there is nothing wrong in the way you use the API.

Comment: You're correct, [further research](http://yizeng.me/2014/02/23/how-to-get-window-size-resize-or-maximize-window-using-selenium-webdriver/) shows that python must use the additional commands. still not sure why normal arguments don't pass. Perhaps this functionality doesn't exist for Mac.