# intern chromeOptions.args window-size seemingly not working

Tags: intern

i'm requiring a capabilities.js file with an object to my intern suites so i can specify which environments to use for various tests. here is my default chrome:

```
chrome: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: [
        // 'start-maximized',
        'window-size=1024x768'
      ]
    }
  }
```

from this i'd expect something like `environments: [caps.chrome]` to open a browser window that is 1024x768. I need to specify window size in a per-environment way. (also, `start-maximized` isn't working- though i do have several mobile emulators set up and doing well).

Comment: Thanks for posting this question as it helped me figure out the correct way of passing chromeOptions parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I did find this which seems to hint that it won't work on a mac. can anyone confirm?

However, the issue linked in the question has been closed for some time.

[Arguments not being applied to Google chromedriver in Selenium with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27309508/arguments-not-being-applied-to-google-chromedriver-in-selenium-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

I use these configs to control windows size on windows, should work on Mac too.

```
"chromeOptions": {
  "args": [
    "--window-size=800,600"
  ]

"chromeOptions": {
  "args": [
    "--start-maximized"
  ]
```